# Select all similar objects (by select keys) from array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, duplicates

How can I filter an array down to all objects that might look similar by certain keys without knowing the value of those keys?

Imagine I have an object like this:

```js
let list = [
  { name: 'Adam',    age: '10', uniqueStuff: 'a'},
  { name: 'Brian',   age: '2',  uniqueStuff: 'b'},
  { name: 'Carley',  age: '15', uniqueStuff: 'c'},
  { name: 'Adam',    age: '2',  uniqueStuff: 'd'},
  { name: 'Christy', age: '15', uniqueStuff: 'e'},
  { name: 'Adam',    age: '10', uniqueStuff: 'f'},
]
```

I want the result to be:

```js
let list = [
  { name: 'Adam',    age: '10', uniqueStuff: 'a'},
  { name: 'Adam',    age: '10', uniqueStuff: 'f'},
]
```

These may *look* like duplicates because they share the same name and age, but `uniqueStuff` is different. So I'm not trying to remove possible duplicates, but to get an array of all similar objects in the array.

Kind of like answering the question "how many kids do we have with the same names *and* same ages?"

This would be similar to MySQL's "having count(*) > 1" queries.

I'm having a really hard time searching for an answer or figuring out a LoDash method. Everything I find is about *removing* duplicates or getting only the duplicates so there's only 1 of each item. Instead, I want to get all the items that are duplicates and have duplicates. So each "match" in my array should have 2 or more items. For example, 2 or more 10-year old Adams, 2 or more 6-year-old Amys, and such.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each match has two or more entries, but do you want different matches in the same array or in separate arrays?  What output do you want to see if `Carley` is changed to `Christy`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N54g9w) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, I would want the array to contain _all_ people with matches. So I had two Christys in my example data, I would expect to see them _with_ the two Adams.

Comment: I _may_ have figured out a way to do this with Lodash's groupBy method, but my implementation is very messy. I'll look at cleaning it up and sharing that solution.

Comment: Did you look at [this approach here](https://tsplay.dev/N54g9w)?  I'm happy to write that up as an answer, if you agree that it meets your needs.  If not, then an elaboration of what you want in the question would be useful (where you [edit] the info into the question).

Comment: @DanielJ.Lewis Did the answer below solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
const reduced = list.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const key = `${curr.name}, ${curr.age}`
    return {
        ...prev,
        [key]: [...(prev[key] || []), curr]
    }
}, {})

const filtered = Object.values(reduced).filter(v => v.length > 1)

const flatted = filtered.flat()
```

You can remove the last line if you prefer having each set of 2 in an array.